# Java doesn't want me to close outputStream before using an inputStream?

Tags: java, android

I've got (an admittedly strange) try/catch block that checks if a `File` exists. If it doesn't, then I create it and write a `File` to it. Then I read the `File`.

I have an `ArrayList` that is being initialized by reading an object from an `ObjectInputStream`. In the original writing of the file using a `FileOutputStream` and an `ObjectOutputStream`, if I call `close()` on them, then my `ArrayList` remains `null`. If I simply remove the calls to `close()`, everything goes as planned.

This seems backwards to me. I would think that the file system is somehow "locked" if I've got some type of `stream` open to it. That's why I thought to close the `outputStreams` before using an `inputStream`. But no, Java won't let this work unless I keep the `outputStreams` open.

Here's my code, including the commented out calls to `close()` which allows this to work properly:

```
try {
                File file = context.getFileStreamPath("file");    
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                try {
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = context.openFileOutput("file", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);

                reminders = new ArrayList<Reminder>();
                objectOutputStream.writeObject(reminders);
//                fileOutputStream.close();
//                objectOutputStream.close();
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                     t.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

         try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = context.openFileInput("file");
            ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
            if (objectInputStream != null) {
                reminders = (ArrayList<Reminder>) objectInputStream.readObject();
            }
        }  catch (Throwable t) {
                     t.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Do you get any exception stack traces?

Comment: The `if (objectInputStream != null)` check ought to be superfluous here (a constructor call can never return `null`).

Comment: It looks like you are writing an empty arraylist to the stream. What happens if you write a record and then close it? It makes me wonder if the outputstream object has allocated some minimal space for your object which hasn't been GC'd unless you close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not close the fileOutputStream.  The close for objectOutputStream will close the fileOutputStream.

Closing the fileOutputStream beafore the objectOutputStream will prevent the objectObjectStream from flushing it's contents to the file, since the fileOutputStream has already been closed.

Not sure why not closing either is allowing the code to work, unless the the objectOutputStream finalize method is flushing the contents when it goes out of scope.

Comment: It doesn't have a finalize() method, and in fact it inherits that from Object, so none of the other base classes have one either.